# Converting tabulated data with arbitrary number of dimensions to multidimensional list

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I've been struggling with this for a while now, hoping someone can help me out. I get so close, but when I get 3 generations in it's not creating an additional list as within the list. I need to keep code light as possible, so trying to avoid 3rd party modules in the end product. Obviously right now I'm using PrettyPrint just to make things easier to check when printing.

### Data

```
Root
    Child 1
    Child 2
        Grandchild 1
        Grandchild 2
            Grandchild's Child 1
            Grandchild's Child 2
    Child 3
    Child 4
            3 Indents in Child 1
            3 Indents in Child 2
Root2
    Child 1
        Grandchild 1
            Grandchild's Child 1
            Grandchild's Child 2
    Child 2
        Grandchild 2
```

### My Code

````py
for line in data_output:
    clean_line = line.lstrip().replace('"', '').replace("'","")

    current_indent = (len(line) - len(clean_line)) / 4

    try:
        previous_indent = (len(data_output[line_incrementer - 1]) - len(data_output[line_incrementer - 1].lstrip())) / 4
        next_indent = (len(data_output[line_incrementer + 1]) - len(data_output[line_incrementer + 1].lstrip())) / 4

        # DEBUG
        # print("prev [" + str(line_incrementer) + "]" + str(previous_indents) + " - next [" + str(line_incrementer) + "]" + str(next_indents) + " - line [" + str(line_incrementer) + "]" + str(line_indents))
    except:
        previous_indent = None
        next_indent = None

    if current_indent == 0:
        parent_list = [clean_line]
        data_dump.append(parent_list)

    elif current_indent > 0 and current_indent != indentation_level:
        active_list = [clean_line]
        parent_list.append(active_list)

    elif current_indent > 0 and current_indent == indentation_level:
        active_list.append(clean_line)
        parent_list = active_list

    indentation_level = current_indent
    line_incrementer += 1

pprint.pprint(data_dump)```
````

### Expected Output

```
[
    ['Root',
        [
        'Child 1',
        'Child 2',
            [
                'Grandchild 1',
                'Grandchild 2'
            ],
        'Child 3',
        'Child 4',
            [
                '3 Indents in Child 1',
                '3 Indents in Child 2'
            ]
        ]
    ],

    ['Root2',
        [
        'Child 1',
            [
                'Grandchild 1',
                [
                    'Grandchilds Child 1',
                    'Grandchilds Child 2'
                ]
            ],
        'Child 2',
            [
                'Grandchild'
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Hi, could you add an example of the expected output?

Comment: Hi @DanielMesejo, thank you for replying. I've added the expected output.